# How can i do a button with 2 labels inside in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, button, textarea

How can i do 1 button with 2 labels with different style inside in android?
(Like the image)
Thank's[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom view. I have used Layout as a button by setting custom button style to the layout and have added two textViews to it, this way:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/customButtonLayout"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content">
<TextView android:text="First" android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000"></TextView>
<TextView android:textColor="#000" android:text="Second"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/secondTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think with which you could applay different textstyles to a Button is to use HTML (with `HTML.fromHTML()`). But I wouldn't recommend that, because probably it wouldn't look good. Use a Layout instead(Linear - or RealtivLayout). Add two TextViews to it and set a selector as the background(to have a "click-effect").